# Layer animation works fine first time, but not on second identical invocation

Tags: iphone, cocoa, core-animation

I have an animation that works perfectly on the first invocation. But if I want to animate the very same layer again, using the same code, it completes immediately  and the `animationDidStop:(CAAnimation *)theAnimation finished:(BOOL)flag` is invoked on the delegate with the `flag` value `NO`.

Here is the code that adds the animation:

```
  imageView.hidden = NO;

  CAKeyframeAnimation* animationOpacity = 
    [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"opacity"];
  ...

  animationOpacity.duration = 2.0;
  animationOpacity.removedOnCompletion = YES;
  animationOpacity.delegate = self;

  [imageView.layer addAnimation:animationOpacity forKey:@"someKey"];
```

and this is the delegate action:

```
-(void) animationDidStop:(CAAnimation *)theAnimation finished:(BOOL)flag {
   imageView.hidden = YES;
}
```

BTW, Initially the `imageView` is visible in the XIB.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out to be a combination of setting `view.hidden = YES` in the callback and calling the animation code from the parent's `viewWillApear`. Once I moved the animation code call into parent's `viewDidApear` instead, things started behaving as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Are you adding the animation again before calling it a second time?  If you aren't then you should set removedOnCompletion = NO

```
animationOpacity.removedOnCompletion = NO;
```

Comment: Code behaves the same with removedOncompletion `YES` or `NO`. I am adding the animation again, exactly the same code is run, including the `addAnimation:...`